# ajax code returning ProgressEvent object rather than my template data

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to improve the UX on a few pages by adding some ajax. I have an ajax request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/search/', true);
xhr.onload = function(data){
   document.getElementById("search-results-container").innerHTML = data; 
}
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
xhr.send(form_data);
```

This isn't giving me the rendered template from my django development server. Instead I get `[object ProgressEvent]` in my `#search-results-container` div. The django view renders correctly if I submit the request synchronously.

I'm probably completely misunderstanding [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), but aren't I supposed to get the template data + http headers straight back from the server? What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Your "load" handler is passed an event object. The response will be available as properties of the XHR object.

Comment: So I should just `xhr.responseText`. Ok, got it. If you paste that I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handlers for XHR events are passed event objects. Newer browsers support the [`ProgressEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent) API. Those won't give you the data from the request, however; for that you'll need to retain access to the XHR object itself. The `.responseText` and (if appropriate) the `.responseXML` properties will contain your response content once the HTTP request has actually completed (which, in your "load" handler, it will have).